# Overlay iframe over another iframe

Tags: jsp, iframe

I have two iframes in a jsp page, one below another. In the end of first iframe I have a dropdown. so when I open the dropdown, its getting hidden by below iframe. How to solve this issue.

I want the dropdown to overlay on another iframe.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If there're no below iframe - does the dropdown display fully? What is used for the dropdown - a standard "select" control?

Comment: Yes, if no iframe in below the dropdown is displayed fully. Yes the standard select control with checkbox in option.

Comment: Standard `<select>` doesn't really have a built-in checkbox, I assume it's some kind of composite control - have you tried set its `z-index` style attribute?

Comment: actually the dropdown has jquery functions for animation. it doesn'yt have z-index style .

Comment: In that case can you set `z-index` of a second iframe to some lower value, e.g. -1?